# Tree output mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have column like

```
1
11
12
2
21
```

I want to display column by desc order like

```
   2
   1
   11
   12
   13
```

That is mean, that i want to order my column by single digits
desc.
How I can do it?
DB - mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select col from my_table order by (case when col = 2 then 0 else col end)
```

Comment: Good idea, I will try it

Answer (score 2):

Just convert the value to a string:

```
order by cast(col as varchar) desc
```

Comment: Doesnt work(
Example of ouput
  |g1   |
| g    |
| f    |
| e    |
| d    |
| c1   |
| c    |
| b11  |
| b1   |
| b  }

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment refers to.  This answer is for the question that you asked.

Answer (score 0):

> Thid will help you....

```
SELECT c.column_name
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.table_name = 'your-table_name'  
ORDER BY c.column_name DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id
FROM
(
SELECT  id,2 as tag FROM test
WHERE id<10
UNION
SELECT id,1 as tag FROM test
WHERE id>=10
) as tmp
ORDER BY tag desc, CASE WHEN tag=2 then id ELSE id*(-1) END DESC
```